# How to consume or process or expose an http endpoint on webhook response?

Tags: java, jwt, docusignapi, webhooks, docusignconnect

I have configured a webhook url in my docusign application, now whenever the status changes, this webhook site is showing a post endpoint with the updated payload, my question is that we are seeing the data(response) on the browser(webhook site), how can we consume that data and use in our application in java

Comment: Is this using JSON or XML payload?

Answer (score 0):

Please see code example in this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/docusign/connect-java-worker-aws).

Essentially the relevant [Java code](https://github.com/docusign/connect-java-worker-aws/blob/master/src/main/java/com/docusign/example/worker/ProcessNotification.java) is this:

```
/**
     * Process the notification message
     * @param test checks whether this is a regular message or test mode message
     * @param xml contains all the information of the envelope
     * @throws Exception failed to create file or failed to save the document - caught at startQueue method
     */
    public static void process(String test, String xml) throws Exception{

        // Guarding against injection attacks
        String pattern = "[^0-9]";
        // Create a Pattern object
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        // Now create matcher object.
        Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(test);
        // Check the incoming test variable to ensure that it ONLY contains the expected data (empty string "", "/break" or integers string)
        // matcher.find() equals true when it finds wrong input
        boolean validInput = test.equals("/break") || test.isEmpty() || !matcher.find();
        if (validInput) {
            if(!test.isEmpty()) {
                // Message from test mode
                processTest(test);
            }
        }
        else {
            System.err.println(DatePretty.date() + "Wrong test value: " + test);
            System.err.println("test can only be: /break, empty string or integers string");
        }
```